# Size Mismatch Runtime Error When Trying to Load a PyTorch Model

Tags: python, pytorch

Below is the code I am trying to run. `fasterrcnn_foodtracker.pth` is the already trained model I am trying to load with PyTorch.

```py
import torch
import torchvision
import cv2

model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

path = '/home/amir/PycharmProjects/Food-Recognition/fasterrcnn_foodtracker.pth'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')), strict=False)
model.eval()

img = cv2.imread('twodishes.jpg')
prediction = model([img])
print(prediction)
```

A runtime error appears with a size mismatch.

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for FasterRCNN:
    size mismatch for roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([100, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([91, 1024]).
    size mismatch for roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([100]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([91]).
    size mismatch for roi_heads.box_predictor.bbox_pred.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([400, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([364, 1024]).
    size mismatch for roi_heads.box_predictor.bbox_pred.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([400]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([364]).
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in previous answers, the error happens because the checkpoint contains weights for a different number of classes.

Setting strict=False when loading the state_dict **does not** fix the error because then only the layers with key mismatches are skipped during the loading.

You can find [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/40859) a solution for the error, which involves first removing the layers with mismatched sizes from the state_dict and only then loading it with strict=False.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
current_model_dict = model.state_dict()
loaded_state_dict = torch.load(path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
new_state_dict={k:v if v.size()==current_model_dict[k].size()  else  current_model_dict[k] for k,v in zip(current_model_dict.keys(), loaded_state_dict.values())}
model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict, strict=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your model configuration does not match the content of the model checkpoint. I imagine your model has parameters such as `input_size`, `output_size` (or `num_classes`) which will eventually define how your model looks like (number of parameters per layer, etc.).

Quick example:

```
# two layer linear 'network', `num_in` input units, `num_out` output units
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(num_in, 100), nn.Linear(100, num_out))
```

If you train and save this model for `num_in = 10` and `num_out = 20`, change these parameters to, say, `num_in = 12` / `num_out = 22` and load your previously saved model, the load routine will complain that the shapes do not match (10 vs. 12 and 20 vs. 22).

This seems to be what is happening to you. The solution: You need to make sure to initialize your model with the same hyperparameters of the model used to generate the checkpoint you are loading.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the model was trained on GPU, but I am trying to load it on CPU?

Comment: Not in terms of parameter counts / model shape, no. You are already loading it to the system memory and not the GPU memory, so you should be good in that regard.

Comment: How would you recommend handling a case when you would like to keep the weights for the early layers, but may have a different FC size for the number of classes at the end of the network?

Comment: @ROS I'm not sure what you are getting at but normally you would discard the last layer and freeze the weights of the previous layers.

Answer (score 0):

Try and load as `pretrained=False`, then update the state dict.. This is because RCNN model was trained on **x** number of classes, but you are trying to match with weights from another model which was probably trained on different number of classes.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on the answer by @Nina. Their answer won't add the size mismatched parameters and will keep the old parameter values. This answer removes the mismatched parameters then loads them manually after.

```
def get_attr(obj, names):
    if len(names) == 1:
        return getattr(obj, names[0])
    else:
        return get_attr(getattr(obj, names[0]), names[1:])

def set_attr(obj, names, val):
    if len(names) == 1:
        return setattr(obj, names[0], val)
    else:
        return set_attr(getattr(obj, names[0]), names[1:], val)

loaded = torch.load("model_to_load.pt")
sized_mismatched_keys = []
for k, v in self.model.state_dict().items():
    if v.size() != loaded['model'][k].size():
        a = set_attr(self.model, k.split("."), None)
        sized_mismatched_keys.append(k)

self.model.load_state_dict(loaded['model'], strict=False)
for missed_key in sized_mismatched_keys:
    set_attr(self.model, missed_key.split("."), torch.nn.Parameter(loaded['model'][missed_key]).to(device))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution, e.g. comments in code.